# Flutter The argument type 'StreamTransformer<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot List<Message>>

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am trying to build a chat application using Flutter & Firebase I took below code from Github and used it on my project. On an earlier version of Flutter, it was working, on 2.0 it is showing the following error: `The argument type 'StreamTransformer<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot, List<Message>>'`

The error is triggered by the following line:

`.transform(Utils.transformer(User.fromJson));`

Full code:

```
class FirebaseApi {
  static Stream<List<User>> getUsers() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      // .collection('ch ats')
      .orderBy(UserField.timestamp, descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(Utils.transformer(User.fromJson));

  static Future uploadMessage(String idUser, String message) async {
    final refMessages =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chats/$idUser/messages');

    final newMessage = Message(
      // idUser: myId,
      idUser: Globals.auth.currentUser!.uid,
      // urlAvatar: myUrlAvatar,
      urlAvatar: ChatPageState.photoUrl.toString(),
      // username: myUsername,
      username: ChatPageState.displayName.toString(),
      message: message,
      createdAt: DateTime.now(),
    );
    await refMessages.add(newMessage.toJson());

    final refUsers = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    await refUsers.doc(idUser).update({UserField.timestamp: DateTime.now()});
  }

  static Stream<List<Message>> getMessages(String idUser) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chats/$idUser/messages')
        .orderBy(MessageField.createdAt, descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .transform(Utils.transformer(Message.fromJson));
  }

}

class Utils {
  static StreamTransformer transformer<T>(
          T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson) =>
      StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot, List<T>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (QuerySnapshot data, EventSink<List<T>> sink) {
          final snaps = data.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
          final users = snaps.map((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();

          sink.add(users);
        },
      );

  static DateTime toDateTime(Timestamp value) {
    // if (value == null);

    return value.toDate();
  }

  static dynamic fromDateTimeToJson(DateTime date) {
    if (date == null) return null;

    return date.toUtc();
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of transform can you try `snapshots.map((e){ // add logo }) .....`

Comment: @Patrick Waweru Hi, I tried to add snapshots.map((e){ // add logo }) it's not working, can you pls elaborate and add it to my code for better understanding?

Comment: You can try [casting](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/05/types-and-casting-in-dart.html)

Comment: @ The Anonymous Koder how i can do that? can you pls make an example using my code.

Comment: @AlMamun then share your models like this Message so that can see your model and  share an example using map instead of transform

Comment: @Patrick Waweru, I am sorry! whcih model you are taking about?

Answer (score 6):

Add `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` as your return type. worked for me.

```
static StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<T>> transformer<T>(
      T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson) =>
  StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<T>>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> data, EventSink<List<T>> sink) {
      final snaps = data.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
      final users = snaps.map((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();

      sink.add(users);
    },
  );
```

Comment: Very explanatory. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that return type of `transformer` function is `dynamic` while `. transform` function requires specific return type. Solution is to add return type like following:

```
static StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot, List<T>> transformer<T>(
      T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson) =>
  StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot, List<T>>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (QuerySnapshot data, EventSink<List<T>> sink) {
      final snaps = data.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
      final users = snaps.map((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();

      sink.add(users);
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

so for any one that experience this problem change your dependency version to this

> firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
> cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+3

it worked for me,  its dependency issue
[image]